# Charmorph for Blender

Tags: modeling

New to Blender and want to use Charmorph. I've had a look at youtube and found a tutorial. However, it doesn't correspond to what I have in Blender 3.2.0. I also cannot find any of the sliders to morph the character. When I finalize, the youtuber showed that it created a rig (like rigify. not sure what that is) but it doesn't look anything like it. Is the latest Blender incompatible with Charmorph as it stands? Am I being a bit thick?

Comment: Since that's a 3rd-party addon, not part of Blender, it's best to ask the author directly. The only video I could see about it is for Blender version 2.83 whcih is a couple of years out of date now.

Comment: Good thought. Thanks, John.